# Does reducing the window to change votes really solve the tactical downvoting problem?

Tags: discussion, voting, locked-votes, tactical-downvoting

The way I see it, the new reduced window to change a vote only imposes a very small cost rather than solving the problem.

Before:

- t0: Good guy answers
- t1: Bad guy copies answer
- t2: Bad guy downvotes good guy and loses a point
- t3: Bad guy, after reaping the benefits of his downvote (let's be conservative and assume he got a single upvote), removes the downvote, getting his point back.
- Summary: +10 points

After:

- t0: Good guy answers
- t1: Bad guy copies answer
- t2: Bad guy downvotes good guy and loses a point
- t3: Bad guy, after reaping the benefits of his downvote (let's be conservative and assume he got a single upvote), tries remove the downvote and fails
- Summary: +9 points

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to talk in terms of cowboys.

Comment: Lucky Luke v/s Joe Dalton?

Comment: What about the "Ugly guy"?

Comment: He always asks about himself

Comment: No, it doesn't.  You can still edit the original, change something minor, and then reverse your vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The votes being permanent make them subject to suspicious voting pattern recognition.

Comment: That's correct. Still, will that solve it? I'd expect, unless the voting pattern recognition tries to match content somehow, that you can still get away with some tactics.

Comment: Also, you could incorporate into the voting pattern recognition the answer_where_there_is_another_answer+downvote_previous_answer+wait+remove dance.

Comment: I'm not sure what will *solve* tactical downvoting, but I think suspicious voting patterns will reveal the worst offenders and alleviate it somewhat.  Just like sock puppet accounts, we'll only be able to detect it if someone uses the tactic a lot.  Hopefully having the downvotes permanently in the database will make people stop and think about how many more times they can do it without being detected.

Comment: I'm not sure if votes are stored after they've been removed by the user, so I don't know if it's possible to detect the "dance".

Comment: So why not a keep the log of the vote, but not keep the actual vote result.  I do it all the time -- audit who makes a change, the value before the change and the value afterwards.  It offers the same detection ability without the limitation of not being able to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Judging by Jarrod's comment on cletus's answer, I may be wrong about that.  It looks like they do keep an audit trail.

Comment: The votes being permanent makes sure that mistaken votes are permanently wrong.

Comment: @endolith: No, not really.

Comment: Why not really?  If I upvote something and then later realize it's wrong (question is clarified, comments on the answer point out a flaw I missed), I can't change my vote.  Visitors to the site are misled, and the answerer gets rep they don't deserve.

Comment: @endolith: As other answers and comments here point out, once a post is edited you can change your vote.  There's nothing truly permanent about the vote.  Besides that, other people voting will normally cancel yours out if you're wrong, so the majority of people will never see it.

Comment: As others point out, the question can be edited in a way that invalidates your vote, but you can't change it.  Subsequent comments can invalidate your vote, but you can't change it.  Locking votes isn't fixing any problem, and it is *causing* a problem so why do it in the first place?  "You can edit the answer to change your vote" is like "Yeah, the law sucks, but we're not changing it.  Just get into a position of power like us and you can break the law with impunity".  People don't vote rationally. A mistaken downvote can cause others to disregard a correct answer.

Comment: @endolith: Once a post is edited, you *can* change your vote.  Locking votes *does* fix a problem.  Since both of your premises are flawed, I won't bother with the rest of your argument.

Comment: I said *question is edited*, not answer.  What problem does locking votes solve?  It doesn't solve tactical downvoting.

Comment: @endolith: And I said *post is edited*.  That includes both questions and answers.  Locking votes has greatly reduced tactical downvoting by making it easier to detect.  It still happens, but now we can remove the offending votes.

Comment: @BilltheLizard  You're a mod.   Can you remember a time when you've used suspicious voting patters to detect revenge downvoting?

Comment: @SamIam Yes. Sockpuppet upvoting is more common, but revenge downvoting also shows up in suspicious vote patterns.

Comment: @BilltheLizard sry, I meant tactical downvoting(as is the topic of this thread)

Comment: @SamIam Ah yeah, that makes more sense. :) No, the information that moderators have access to won't reveal tactical downvoting. Only employees would have access to that level of detail. (Unless, of course, they actually go to the trouble of editing and undo-ing all of their downvotes, which anyone would be able to see a history of.)

Comment: Your answer fails to point out why voting patterns could not be recognised if votes can be changed, as a matter of fact, if tactical voting is about changing your vote, allowing that seems crucial to detecting it...

Comment: @ufotds Moderators can't see your votes, but they can see edits. There are several comments here that explain this in detail.

Answer (score 9):

As I see it, a big part of the tactical downvoting problem was the ability to undo your downvotes and hide your tracks.

Just as an observation: we've had at least three semi-serious exploits all based on the ability to "undo" things. Which suggests that "undo" is kind of a dangerous ability, certainly far more than I realized.

Comment: Just curious, but what exploits? Anything you can share?

Comment: Any time you have a `delete` from a database, bad things can happen to good people, so it doesn't surprise me that the "undo" functions have caused issues. Though, like cletus, I'm curious :)

Comment: Man... I'm guessing this bodes ill for the "undo close vote" feature... :-(

Comment: Undo is not a dangerous ability, lack of trail is. You can certainly have undo and log everything, which makes it automatically non dangerous.

Comment: Vinko, we already do. All the votes are there with their DeletionDate field set to a date value. The exploits have to do with the *ability to undo*, period.

Comment: How so? Votes are anonymous. Bad guy still gains upvotes by downvoting another answers. He just wins a bit less, but still wins. Other people might think he has downvoted them, but they cannot be sure, only backend people can tell for sure (either via the trail or via the permanent record.) Period!

Comment: Vinko, get back to me when you've actually tried this tactic with the new time limit. It's quite severe.

Comment: Jeff, Do you as moderator have the opportunity to investigate and locate these patterns, so it is possible to find users that do this a lot? If so, you could maybe locate the users that seems to do this a lot, and ban them from the community. If not already there, create a reporting tool that points out suspicious patterns.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest hole I think is that if you have 2,000+ rep you can edit a post you downvoted, which counts as an edit, and then revert your vote. It's probably not hard to find some typo to ostensibly fix either.

There's another problem with this worth mentioning: when you first post or when you make an edit you have 5 minutes to make changes that don't count as an edit. That's a good thing. The problem is that if you downvote for a serious problem and that problem is fixed fairly quickly, by the time you see that you can't reverse your downvote because no edit has been triggered.

This is especially a problem if the window to change your mind has been narrowed greatly.

Has that been considered in this?

Comment: This will make it even easier to find bad behavior - we never delete votes, only set a deletion date on the records.

Comment: I do think this is a loophole, but I think a lot of people in the community will get suspicious if it happens a lot.

Comment: I think it'd be hard to define suspicious activity for this. After all, I think there is a far greater likelihood of you answering a question where you also edit the question or other answers.

Comment: that makes it *quite* a bit more work, multiple form submissions, versus the "just a few quick clicks" that we had before.

Comment: Then what exactly narrowing the window solves? If you have a trail of undos you can havve the voting pattern algorithm use the trail, can't you?

Comment: @Vinko: Narrowing the window is what makes it more work for the exploiter.  Instead of just clicking everyone down, then coming back and clicking everyone back up later, now they have to go in and edit every answer they downvoted in order to reclaim the votes.

Comment: @Bill: If they have a trail they can program a detection algorithm that would detect this behavior just as well as they can now, which is what makes the narrowing worth it. Because a single point (or even ten) makes the gamble valuable to bad guy. The cost is not a deterrent, the chance of being caught is. The chance of being caught (should be) is the same given that you have a trail.

Comment: @Vinko: I mostly agree.  I agree the cost in points is negligible, a non-issue to an exploiter.  The cost in *time* will be a deterrent to a lot of people.  Having to edit a bunch of answers so I can reclaim one point isn't worth the effort.  To the most determined exploiters, only the risk of getting caught will be a deterrent (and that, not always).  I'm still hoping for a clarification from a dev on the audit trail.

Comment: @Bill: Seems like Jeff thinks that community policing will be enough. If downvoters cannot hide behind an undo it will be evident to the rest who can then flag or denounce. Seems like the trail does exist but is not used in this manner.