# Canceling a "Vote to Close"

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

This is similar to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close), but not the same. The other question is more along the lines of someone else being able to provide a "vote **not** to close" to counter a "vote to close". My question is about being able to cancel your **own** vote to close.

There have been a few occassions where I voted to close a question for some reason (other than it should be migrated) and then the question has been reworded (either by the original questioner or someone else, which should be irrelevant) resulting in a question that negates the reason specified to close the question. At that point, it would be nice if I could then cancel my own vote to close.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: (FWIW, i agree - this is badly needed, and has been requested several times dating back to the UserVoice days... Sadly, the SO Team appears to have been burned by undo and is backing off their initial enthusiasm for it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/does-reducing-the-window-to-change-votes-really-solve-the-tactical-downvoting-pro/18374#18374 )

Comment: Now I'm in the dilemma... should I undo the "close exact duplicate"?

Comment: @Shog9: I think there are other ways to solve the problems removing undo capabilities and limiting the time allowed to do them were meant to solve.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I didn't see the question you and Shog9 referenced as the duplicate and after reading it, they are duplicates although I like mine better. :) Anyway, I don't think there is a need to undo the "close as duplicate".

Comment: @Scott: I think so too. But suggestions regarding closing seem to get highjacked by the "don't close anything" crowd.

Comment: I was just making light... I'll add a `<g>` next time...

Comment: @Marc: do that, and i'll reply "LOL" - then we'll both get flagged.