# You should be able to vote to reopen a question before it is actually closed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, reopen-closed

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Canceling a “Vote to Close”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18790/canceling-a-vote-to-close)
>   [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

Granted, you can't reopen something that isn't closed yet, but that is a vocabulary issue that is easily addressed, please hear me out.

There have been a few instances where I have been browsing Stack Overflow questions, and have come across a question with 3 or 4 votes to close for one reason or another, however, I just don't agree that it should be closed.  Now, if it is closed, I may notice it later, and come back to it to cast my vote to reopen the question.  However, it is much more likely that I will not notice.  And a question that I would have voted to reopen, doesn't get my vote.

The question then becomes how many yays to nays do you need to actually close a question, and how many yays to nays do you need to actually reopen it, but once a good balance is struck, I feel this would improve a feature of the site that some have taken issue with.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33244/some-thoughts-about-closing-reopening-questions

Comment: Can you say "tug of war?" No, not enough questions get closed as it is ...

Comment: They'll implement this just as soon as they implement a feature that allows us to close a question before it's asked.

Comment: deferred to duplicates