# We should be able to add reopen votes while the question is still not closed

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
>   [You should be able to vote to reopen a question before it is actually closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/you-should-be-able-to-vote-to-reopen-a-question-before-it-is-actually-closed)

The reopen link, I think should be visible, under a different name, once there's at least one close vote. Perhaps it should be named "unclose", to deduce by one the number of votes to close.

Otherwise, what happens is this:

1. the question is considered perfectly OKay by the crowd,
2. then comes angry mob and slowly closes the question. While close votes grow there's nothing you can do.
3. After the question is closed, it's completely off-radar and it takes very long time to reopen it.

Comment: Duplicate of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/you-should-be-able-to-vote-to-reopen-a-question-before-it-is-actually-closed), and by extension [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close).

Comment: are you out of votes @grace?

Comment: @Juan I was weighing out which question to cast my vote under.

Comment: There was only one candidate (contrary to lost)