# Why is there no way to vote that a question should not be closed?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [You should be able to vote to reopen a question before it is actually closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/you-should-be-able-to-vote-to-reopen-a-question-before-it-is-actually-closed)
>   [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

I find it strange that one has to wait for a question to get close before one can vote to reopen it. It should be possible to vote against closing a question, and for reopening it after it has gotten closed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18790/canceling-a-vote-to-close

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Or, maybe I missed the point entirely.

There is. It's an option for moderators and members with 3k+ rep. See [Privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

If you have had a question closed and wish for it to be re-opened, edit the content to make it more relevant (if possible) then flag the question for moderator attention and request re-opening.

Comment: David's question is about a question that has close votes. You can't case a reopen vote until the question is closed.  So he is asking why that is.  (At least that is how I read his question).

Comment: @jzd, it seems, after re-reading the question, you're right and I missed the point.