# Should the vote lock-in time be extended?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isn't the “vote too old to be changed” a little too eager?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/isnt-the-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-a-little-too-eager)

I think that voting should take at least a day to lock in. Someone could vote down accidentally on a good post, and then, 5 min later, the vote would be locked in.

Comment: See [Does reducing the window to change votes really solve the tactical downvoting problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/does-reducing-the-window-to-change-votes-really-solve) for the reasoning, and the outcome of [Why can't I change my vote if the post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited/38759#38759) for a more recent relaxing to 5 minutes. (And may I suggest you get to learn these sites a bit before making all these suggestions...? Welcome!)

Comment: @Arjan: Ok :P :D

Comment: There are legitimate times where vote lock-in is a pain (even though it does serve a useful purpose), but I'm not seeing "Someone could vote down accidentally on a good post, and then, 5 min later, the vote would be locked in." If it takes you more than 5 minutes to reverse an accidental downvote you're doing something wrong

Comment: @MichaelMrozek more likely is what happened to me today: Vote up an answer that has convincing arguments, then read through several more answers before landing on one that unequivocally shows how the first answer is wrong (with citations and all), only to find out it has been 8 minutes since my vote on the first answer... and of course I don't have 2,000 reputation on the site to edit the post even trivially.

Comment: Yes, it should be extended to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree.

Whenever that happens, one could just post a comment with a friendly request to make a minor edit in the post so that the downvote can be removed, or just edit the post themselves if one has enough reputation to edit other's posts.