# Why are votes locked after a period of time?

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, undo

I upvoted an answer a while ago, but I realized it was not a good answer. The system does not allow me to take it away, but it allows me to upvote answers long after I have seen it. Shouldn't I be able to unupvote if I'm allowed to vote?

Comment: The system does not track when you saw an answer

Comment: After the edit the question is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98673/can-we-get-rid-of-locked-votes-or-have-a-longer-grace-period

Comment: I am not requesting for a longer grace period